# Python 3, 2D List - Adjust Values of Neighboring Cells (Homework)

Tags: python, python-3.x, conways-game-of-life

**NOTE: I can not import anything like pygame or numpy.**

Working on a version of Conway's Game of Life, and I was able to get a "U" shape moving around. At this point I've got no clue on how to adjust values of the neighboring cells, or if it's even possible with my code.

In the function "setInitialPatternList" I've added if statements to print out "PASS" to see if I'm on the right track. From what it's printing out, I can tell it's not looking at all of the "X"s I have individually. I'm unsure of where to go at this point, or if my "if" functions in "setInitialPatternList" need to be moved elsewhere.

I need help trying to figure out how I can adjust the cells neighboring the "X"s on the board.

```
from random import randint
from os import system

MAX_ROW = 30
MAX_COL = 60
currentGen = []
tempGen = []

def displayMenu():
    print("[P]lay – Press 'P' to play.")
    print("[Q]uit – Press 'Q' to exit.\n")

def setZeroList(listName):
    for row in range(MAX_ROW):
        for col in range(MAX_COL):
            listName[row][col] = "."

def setInitialPatternList(listToFormat):
    rowChoice = randint(0,MAX_ROW-7)
    columnChoice = randint(0,MAX_COL-7)
    for foundation in range(1,7):
        listToFormat[rowChoice + foundation][columnChoice] = "X"
        listToFormat[rowChoice + foundation][columnChoice + 6] = "X"
        listToFormat[rowChoice + 6][columnChoice + foundation] = "X"
        counter = 0
    if listToFormat[rowChoice + 1][columnChoice] == "X":
        print("Check1")
    if listToFormat[rowChoice - 1][columnChoice] == "X":
        print("Check2")
    if listToFormat[rowChoice][columnChoice + 1] == "X":
        print("Check3")
    if listToFormat[rowChoice][columnChoice - 1] == "X":
        print("Check4")
    if listToFormat[rowChoice + 1][columnChoice + 1] == "X":
        print("Check5")
    if listToFormat[rowChoice + 1][columnChoice - 1] == "X":
        print("Check6")
    if listToFormat[rowChoice - 1][columnChoice - 1] == "X":
        print("Check7")
    if listToFormat[rowChoice - 1][columnChoice + 1] == "X":
        print("Check8")
    if counter == 0:
        print("Counter Check")

def copyList(tempList, currentList):
    for row in range(MAX_ROW):
        for col in range(MAX_COL):
            currentList[row][col] =  tempList[row][col]

def displayList(currentList):
    MAX_ROW = 30
    MAX_COL = 60
    for row in range(MAX_ROW):
        for col in range(MAX_COL):
            if (col == (MAX_COL - 1)):
                print(currentList[row][col], end = "\n")
            else:
                print(currentList[row][col], end = "")

def displaySubMenu():
    print("[S]top - Press 'S' to stop.")

for row in range(MAX_ROW):
    currentGen.append([0] * MAX_COL)
for row in range(MAX_ROW):
    tempGen.append([0] * MAX_COL)

displayMenu()
setZeroList(tempGen)
setInitialPatternList(tempGen)
copyList(tempGen, currentGen)
displayList(currentGen)

while(True):
    userResponses = ["q", "p"]
    while(True):
        playOrQuit = input(">>").lower()
        if(playOrQuit in userResponses):
            break
        else:
            continue

    if(playOrQuit == "p"):
        system("clear") #Change to cls
        displayMenu()
        setZeroList(tempGen)
        setInitialPatternList(tempGen)
        copyList(tempGen, currentGen)
        displayList(currentGen)
    else:
        system("clear") #Change to cls
        break
```

Comment: So...what's your question?

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize there wasn't a question in there.
How would I go about seeing and/or changing the neighboring cells?

Comment: I believe the program is supposed to automatically progress as outlined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life  But it looks like it's only ever dropping into the first if block of `setInitialPatternList()`

Comment: Yes. Every time the user enters "P", I want the cells adjacent the X's to change based on how many other X's are. I thought my "if" statements would at least be able to "look" at adjacent cells, then from there I would figure out how to make the changes I need.

Comment: First, your `if` statements are close, but they have a serious problem: what happens when `rowChoice` is `0`? `rowChoice-1` is `-1`, which you don't want to check (unless you wanted a torus rather than a plane, which wraps around at the edges). You need to guard against that and not check upward when you're on row 0 (and likewise at each edge, of course, not just the top.)

Comment: Next, to evolve the game one step, you need to write a function that does that. The function will need to loop over all of the cells, and it will need those `if` statements to check the neighbors, and it will need to actually count them (like `x_neighbors += 1`), not just print something out, and then do something with that count (that's where the Life rules come into play).

Comment: One last thing: make sure you don't modify the array while you're still walking it. For example, when you're evaluating position `(1, 1)`, you need to use the previous step's `(0, 0)` and `(0, 1)` and `(0, 2)` and `(1, 0)`, not the new values you already computed for the next step. So, your `evolve` function is going to have to build up a new array as it goes, not change the current one.